# How to implement proper locking in APEX?

Tags: apex

I'm trying to implement *locking* in sake of not having duplicates. The problem is it works only with this line *System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'duplicateCallLog.size() == 0 - '+ duplicateCallLog.size());*. It sounds like *System.debug* call guarantees that result of insert will be available in other instances of controllers. Is there any procedure in APEX aka *commit* or *saveChanges* that grants data in database? Or there any other *locking* patterns in APEX?

```
   List<CallLog__c> duplicateCallLog = [SELECT Id FROM CallLog__c WHERE SessionID__c = :sessionId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1];
        if(duplicateCallLog.size() == 0)
        {
           System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'duplicateCallLog.size() == 0 - '+ duplicateCallLog.size());
           insert newCallLog;
           newCallLog = [SELECT Id FROM CallLog__c WHERE SessionID__c = :sessionId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1];
           callLogId = newCallLog.Id; 
        }
        else{
           System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'duplicateCallLog.size() != 0 - '+ duplicateCallLog.size());            
           callLogId = null;     
        }
```

Comment: About locking patterns -- you can read http://advancedapex.com/. I would recommend you to do your fix on trigger level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the "FOR UPDATE" keyword on your SOQL calls.

A great resource is [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm)

The idea is that you can do the following:

```
List<Contact> contact = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :idSet FOR UPDATE]
```

This will allow you to lock the records while you are editing and ensure that no other processes modify the records you pull from the database.

Comment: I need something that will lock whole table

Comment: I'd suggest reading the linked article as it goes over what your asking about.